# angular router: use array as parameter

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to match a route with an array parameter, e.g. the url produced by:

```
this.router.navigate(['users', ['a', 'b', 'c']]);
```

is `http://localhost:4200/users;0=a;1=b;2=c`.

How do I match against this array and retreive it from the paramMap later? I tried

```
{ path: 'users/:ids', component: UsersComponent },
```

which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of solutions

I will give you the faster one

1 * make join for your ids

```
let ids = ['a', 'b', 'c'].join(",");
```

2 * you send it in queryParams

```
this.router.navigate(['users'], { queryParams: { ids: ids } });
```

you will see url like this

```
http://localhost:4200/users?ids=a,b,c
```

3 * in the users component you make this

```html
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {

   this.route
   .queryParams
   .subscribe(params => {
     let ids = params['ids'];
     console.log(ids.split(","));
   }, error => {
     console.log(error);
     
   });

    }
```

I hope that will help you

Comment: This helped me, although I don't think this is the proper/best solution for my exact question. Your answer isn't compatible with ids which contain a comma. But there is `params.getAll('ids')` which I ended up using. Your solution made me come up with a workaround, but it is probably not exactly the right answer. Thanks anyways!